# Use RegExp to match a parenthetical number then increment it

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've been trying to find a way to match a number in a Javascript string that is surrounded by parenthesis at the end of the string, then increment it.

Say I have a string:

```
var name = "Item Name (4)";
```

I need a RegExp to match the (4) part, and then I need to increment the 4 then put it back into the string.

This is the regex I have so far:

```
\b([0-9]+)$\b
```

This regex does not work. Furthermore, I do not know how to extract the integer retrieved and put it back in the same location in the string.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your regexp syntax require you to escape literal '('s and ')'s? Some do.

Comment: I'll look into that, I still need help with the other stuff though. Thanks so far!

Comment: The evaluation and increment of the number is never done with regexp, but with the programming language at hand. Regexo only finds and replaces strings and cannot do aritmethics.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The replace method can take a function as its second argument. It gets the match (including submatches) and returns the replacement string. Others have already mentioned that the parentheses need to be escaped.

```
"Item Name (4)".replace(/\((\d+)\)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
    return "(" + (Number(n) + 1) + ")";
});
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Often the function form of replace is the only convenient way to combine the power of the builtin-regexp scanner, with the free-form power of user-defined functions. I've even used closures to have "stateful" functions with replace().

Answer (score 0):

I can can only think of a way of doing it in three steps: Extract, increment and replace.

```
// Tested on rhino
var name = "Item Name (4)";
var re = /\((\d+)\)/;

match = re.exec(name);
number = parseInt(match[1]) + 1;
name = name.replace(re, "(" + number + ")");
```

The important parts of the pattern:

1. You need to escape the parens to match literal parens
2. You also need the to use parens to capture the number so that you can extract it from the match.
3. \d matches a digit and is shorter and more common than writing out [0-9].

Answer (score 0):

In order this pattern to work you shoud escape parenthesis. In addition \b and $ are unneeded. Thus

```
var s = "Item Name (4)"; 
var match = /\((\d+)\)/.exec( s ); 
var n = Number(match[1])+1; 
alert( s.replace( /\(\d+\)/, '('+n+')' ) );
```

Solution by david.clarke (tested)

```
"Item Name (4)".replace(/\(([0-9]+)\)/, '('+(1+RegExp.$1) + ')');
```

But I think it is too concise

**UPD**: It turned out that RegExp.$1 can't be used as part of replace parameter, because it works only in Opera

Comment: 1 + RegExp.$1  always returns 1 for me.

Answer (score -1):

`'var name = "Item Name (4)"'.replace(/\(([\d]+)\)/, 1 + $1);`

(untested)

Comment: It's much more consise though ;-)

Comment: Doesn't work because `$1` is a string (even if it wasn't a syntax error).