# passing variable to a regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)

I have a msg like this:

> **Max {0} chars allowed in {1}**

And I have a function to create a message using the arguments passed as

```
for(var i = 0; i < agrs.length; i++){
    reg = new RegExp('\{'+i+'\}', 'gi');
    key = key.replace(reg,agrs[i])
}
```

The problem is that it's not able to take the param `i` to create the reg exp.

What's the way to achieve this?

Comment: @casperOne, what is the duplicate? Neither [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029109/javascript-regex-how-to-put-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression) nor [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript) were the same as this question. This question is important because it shows actually mixing a string variable into a regex pattern, whereas the other questions' answers only provided examples where escaping characters was not an issue.

Comment: I agree with MandM. And given that this question has been marked by duplicate we cannot update the answers with ES6 JS, and people will keep using verbose JS. @casperOne can you unmark this as duplicate?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Your regexp is `/{0}/gi` since you create it from a string. And it is not a valid expression.
You need to escape { in the regexp because it has a special meaning in the regexp syntax, so it should be:

```
new RegExp('\\{'+i+'\\}', 'gi');
```

which is `/\\{0\\}/gi`. You need to *escape* the escaping `\\` in the string.

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly encourage you to use the functional form of [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/Replace) to solve your problem, rather than trying to parametrize the regexp in a for-loop that iterates over {0},{1},etc.

In other words, rather than look for '{0}' or '{1}', just look for '{([0-9]+)}' (i.e. {}'s surrounding an arbitrary number, and pass a function to the replace() function to intelligently replace these expressions based on the number between the {}'s. This lets you use a RegExp literal which you can write as /{([0-9]+)}/ rather than mess around with escape characters in strings.

Something like this:

```
s='the song says {0} little {1} little {2} little-endians';
args=['zero','one','two'];
new_string = s.replace(/{([0-9]+)}/g, function(wholematch,firstmatch)
  {return args[(+firstmatch)]; }
);
```

which yields

```
the song says zero little one little two little-endians
```

See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423107).

edit: if you want to leave alone items that are greater than the length of your `args` list, make sure to sanity-check the parameter number:

```
s='the song says {0} little {1} little {2} little-endians,\n'+
  ' {3} little {4} little {5} little-endians';
args=['zero','one','two'];
new_string = s.replace(/{([0-9]+)}/g, function(wholematch,firstmatch)
  {var i = +firstmatch; return i < args.length ? args[i] : wholematch;}
);
```

which yields

```
the song says zero little one little two little-endians,
 {3} little {4} little {5} little-endians
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your second line is supposed to be

```
reg = new RegExp('\{'+i+'\}', 'gi');
```

but I don't know if that's your only problem or not.

Comment: Yep it is like that, but it does not allow to create one. Says "invalid quantifier".

Answer (score 1):

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

var re = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(str));
```

See: [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex/6969486#6969486)