# Javascript Regex: How to put a variable inside a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

So for example:

```
function(input){
    var testVar = input;
    string = ...
    string.replace(/ReGeX + testVar + ReGeX/, "replacement")
}
```

But this is of course not working :)
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Be aware that if you let the user supply this variable, it's easy for a malicious user to crash your application via catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: what is "ReGeX"? is it a variable name? it makes answers confusing by implying that it is a part of RegExp construction (in case a reader did not see those weird characters in the question).

Answer (score 387, accepted):

```
const regex = new RegExp(`ReGeX${testVar}ReGeX`);
...
string.replace(regex, "replacement");
```

#### Update

Per some of the comments, it's important to note that you may want to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) the *variable* if there is potential for malicious content (e.g. the variable comes from user input)

#### ES6 Update

In 2019, this would usually be written using a template string, and the above code has been updated. The original answer was:

```
var regex = new RegExp("ReGeX" + testVar + "ReGeX");
...
string.replace(regex, "replacement");
```

Comment: Make sure to escape your string! See @zzzzBov answer

Comment: This is not working in my case, can you please have a look [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojvpsm6q/) and let me know if what i have to do if I want to set a country code dynamic into `regex` expression

Comment: One important thing to remember is that in regular strings the \ character needs to be escaped while in the regex literal (usually) the / character needs to be escaped. So `/\w+\//i` becomes `new RegExp("\\w+/", "i")`

Comment: How about the /g?

Comment: did you able to run this example I run it and got errors last one string not defined, please test code before share it

Answer (score 99):

You can use the RegExp object:

```
var regexstring = "whatever";
var regexp = new RegExp(regexstring, "gi");
var str = "whateverTest";
var str2 = str.replace(regexp, "other");
document.write(str2);
```

Then you can construct `regexstring` in any way you want.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

Comment: var characterCount = parseInt(attrs.limitCharacterCount);
      console.log(characterCount);
      var specialCharactersValidation = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{"+characterCount+"}$/");

/\/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$\//
requestShipmentDirectives.js:76 false
main.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

This is what is happening when I make the RegEx Dynamic.

Answer (score 49):

To build a regular expression from a variable in JavaScript, you'll need to use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor with a string parameter.

```
function reg(input) {
    var flags;
    //could be any combination of 'g', 'i', and 'm'
    flags = 'g';
    return new RegExp('ReGeX' + input + 'ReGeX', flags);
}
```

of course, this is a very naive example. It assumes that `input` is has been properly escaped for a regular expression. If you're dealing with user-input, or simply want to make it more convenient to match special characters, you'll need to [escape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript):

```
function regexEscape(str) {
    return str.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
}

function reg(input) {
    var flags;
    //could be any combination of 'g', 'i', and 'm'
    flags = 'g';
    input = regexEscape(input);
    return new RegExp('ReGeX' + input + 'ReGeX', flags);
}
```

Comment: The only way this worked for me was if I deleted `ReGeX` text. So I used: `return new RegExp(input, flags);`

Comment: @MichaelRader, yes, the "ReGeX" text was part of the question and used as an example, not as something that's required to make the code work.

Comment: lol just realized that was just your placeholder, but as a noob this took me awhile to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: I understand why string needs to be escaped. But why '\\$&' is used as a replacement

Comment: ``\\`` represents a single ``\`` character, [`$&` is the matched substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Answer (score 10):

You can create regular expressions in JS in one of two ways:

1. Using regular expression literal - `/ab{2}/g`
2. Using the regular expression constructor - `new RegExp("ab{2}", "g")` .

Regular expression literals are constant, and can not be used with variables. This could be achieved using the constructor. The stracture of the RegEx constructor is

```
new RegExp(regularExpressionString, modifiersString)
```

You can embed variables as part of the regularExpressionString. For example,

```
var pattern="cd"
var repeats=3
new RegExp(`${pattern}{${repeats}}`, "g")
```

This will match any appearance of the pattern `cdcdcd`.

Answer (score 7):

if you're using es6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are an option...

```
string.replace(new RegExp(`ReGeX${testVar}ReGeX`), "replacement")
```

Comment: it doesn't work with template literals. 
I'm using regexp to validate password in my app, and I wanted to parametrize max and min length in my regular expression string and it doesn't work.

```
 const newRegExp = new RegExp(`^[^\s]{${4},${32}}$`);

export const validatePassword = value => value.match(newRegExp);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always give regular expression as string, i.e. `"ReGeX" + testVar + "ReGeX"`. You'll possibly have to escape some characters inside your string (e.g., double quote), but for most cases it's equivalent.

You can also use `RegExp` constructor to pass flags in ([see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)).

Answer (score 3):

It's only necessary to prepare the string variable first and then convert it to the RegEx.

for example:

You want to add `minLength` and `MaxLength` with the variable to RegEx:

```
function getRegEx() {
    const minLength = "5"; // for exapmle: min is 5
    const maxLength = "12"; // for exapmle: man is 12

    var regEx = "^.{" + minLength + ","+ maxLength +"}$"; // first we make a String variable of our RegEx
    regEx = new RegExp(regEx, "g"); // now we convert it to RegEx

    return regEx; // In the end, we return the RegEx
}
```

now if you change value of `MaxLength` or `MinLength`, It will change in all RegExs.

Hope to be useful. Also sorry about my English.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an pretty useless function that return values wrapped by specific characters. :)

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/squadjot/43agwo6x/

```
function getValsWrappedIn(str,c1,c2){
    var rg = new RegExp("(?<=\\"+c1+")(.*?)(?=\\"+c2+")","g"); 
    return str.match(rg);
    }

var exampleStr = "Something (5) or some time (19) or maybe a (thingy)";
var results =  getValsWrappedIn(exampleStr,"(",")")

// Will return array ["5","19","thingy"]
console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 2):

accepted answer doesn't work for me and doesn't follow [MDN examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

see the 'Description' section in above link

I'd go with the following it's working for me:

```
let stringThatIsGoingToChange = 'findMe';
let flagsYouWant = 'gi' //simple string with flags
let dynamicRegExp = new RegExp(`${stringThatIsGoingToChange}`, flagsYouWant)

// that makes dynamicRegExp = /findMe/gi
```

Comment: It still works. The issue is that  'ReGeX' + testVar +' ReGeX'  makes the solution confusing.  
Adding an actually example would  clear things up in my opinion.
    var testVar = '321';
    var regex = new RegExp(  "["   +   testVar   +   "]{2}",   "g" );
    //  above equivalent to   /[321]{2}/g