# How to include a variable in a regex expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Regex: How to put a variable inside a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029109/javascript-regex-how-to-put-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)

I'm using the following for as regex pattnern in a [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org) fakeServer response:

```
/https:\/\/ca-davstorage:8080\/myFile.json(\?.*|$)/
```

I would like to replace `myFile` with a variable, but as I'm not really good at regex, I'm struggling to get it to work.
Currently I have this, but it does not seem to work.

```
'https:\\/\\/ca-davstorage:8080\\/'+myFile+'.json(\\?.*|$)/'
```

**Question**:
How to I correctly add a variable to a regex?

Thanks for help!

Comment: @FelixKling: ah, yes. Sorry for re.asking...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `/regex/` use the constructor function `RegExp`.

**Example**:

```
var foo = 'bar',
    re = new RegExp('[0-9]' + foo, 'g');
re.test('1bar'); //true
```

The first argument of the RegExp constructor is the regular expression, the second one is the modifier.

Comment: ok. let me try if I can fit this into my function.

Comment: ok. Worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that my answer helped.