# How to pass a variable in replace function

Tags: javascript, html, regex, javascript-objects

I have been using the replace function since long to remove the classes from JavaScript, Now I was making the JavaScript function for that through which, I can pass an element and the class name to remove the class from the same.

```
changeAddress.className = changeAddress.className.replace(new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + 'hide' + '(?:\\s|$)'), ' ');
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("MyID").className =
    document.getElementById("MyID").className.replace(/\bMyClass\b/,'');
```

So can someone suggest me how to pass the class "hide" and "MyClass" Dynamically in the same?

Comment: The answer to your literal question is here: [Javascript Regex: How to put a variable inside a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029109/javascript-regex-how-to-put-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression). However, there is a much better solution for the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the class from an element, use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API

```
document.getElementById('MyID').classList.remove('MyClass');
```

Comment: Seems like a conflict between answering the literal question (or closing as a duplicate in this case) and providing the right solution to the problem :-/ Good answer! Feel free to reopen the question.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks. I've reopened question. :)

Comment: Yes.. @FelixKling I believe this is a better solution for my problem, that's why I have accepted this as the solution.