# How to create Regular Expressions from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm stuck at assignment. 
I want to create a regex based on a string sent to function.
If I send for example dd/mm/yyyy,  I want it to create  `(\d\d)[\/](\d\d)[\/](\d\d\d\d)`  and if yyyy/mm/dd I need it in reverse so I can later use it for date validation?
Is this even possible?

Comment: I tried 2 days to think of it with for loops appending, index of, and i got nowhere. Beacuse   of that i don't know if it's even posible. I don't need solution i need hint.

Comment: Javascript is a Turing complete language, so anything is possible :^)

Comment: The simplest (to understand/develop) method would be to loop through each character, if it's a "/" add the `[\/]` part, otherwise add `\d`.   Add the brackets `()` with the `[\/]` and at the start/end.

Comment: The next step would be to use `.replace` instead of a loop to change characters, eg: `x.replace(/m/g, "\\d")`.  The least obvious part of this is to add the brackets `()` at the same time as the `[\/]` and add them at the start/end directly.

Comment: Problem is not just spliting beacuse input can be dot or slash or horizontal line. Thats why I'm stuck :)

Comment: @user3187715 you can't say you want to convert "dd/mm/yyyy" to a regex, then, when people give you suggestions, you add a whole bunch of other requirements such as dots and slashes.   so move on from .split, you shouldn't still be "stuck".

Comment: The task is much more complicated than that. I need to take any input and convert it not just one with slashes

Answer (score 0):

[How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

[Javascript Regex: How to put a variable inside a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029109/javascript-regex-how-to-put-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)

I think that's what you are trying to do ? Get user input and use it with RegEx ?

You can use .split() to get an array out of string, and then work with that array.
You can use .reverse() and .join() if you need it later.