# Issue with creating a Regular Expression from variable

Tags: javascript

I am not able to create a regex from a variable, using template literals

What is wrong and how to fix it?

```
const myValue = 'a.b'
const reg = new RegExp(`/^${myValue}$/`);
/*
  /^a.b/
*/
```

Comment: This should help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029109/javascript-regex-how-to-put-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression][1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the slashes from the template literal. Slashes inside the string are escaped by the constructor, and included as part of the pattern.

```js
const myValue = 'a.b'
const reg = new RegExp(`^${myValue}$`);
/*
  /^a.b$/
*/

console.log(reg);
```