# Double bracket pattern search in string

Tags: javascript

I have a regular expression to search in a string.

```
new RegExp("\\b"+searchText+"\\b", "i")
```

My strings:

```
"You are likely to find [[children]] in [[a school]]"
"[[school]] is for [[learning]]"
```

How can I search only the words in double brackets?

A regular expression should contain searchText as a function argument.

Comment: Do you want exact matches only, or partial matches too?

Comment: Can you please add your expected output more? give some examples

Comment: searchText - is a function argument.

Comment: so i'm trying to find a whole word (searchText) in brackets.

Answer (score 4):

This RegEx will give you the basics of what you want:

```
\[\[[^\]]*\]\]
```

- `\[\[` matches the two starting brackets. A bracket is a special character in RegEx, hence it must be escaped with `\`
- `[^\]]*` is a negated set that matches zero or more of any character **except** a closing bracket. This matches the content in-between the brackets.
- `\]\]` matches the two closing brackets.

Here's a very basic example of what you could do with this:

```js
let string = "You are likely to find [[children]] in [[a school]]<br>[[school]] is for [[learning]]";

string = string.replace(/\[\[[^\]]*\]\]/g, x => `<mark>${x}</mark>`);

document.body.innerHTML = string;
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I add a searchText variable (function argument) to a regular expression?

Comment: You could just replace `[^\]]*` with `searchText`; *e.g*. `new RegExp("\[\[" + searchText + "\]\]", "g")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```js
var str = `-- You are likely to find [[children]] in [[a school]]
-- [[school]] is for [[learning]]`;
var regex = /(?<=(\[\[))([\w\s]*)(?=(\]\]))/gm;
var match = str.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```

Comment: It's the class (`[...]`), if you need, you can add more to this!

Comment: Check my answer. (`[ ...]`) is not a class

Comment: Ah, `[...]` is called character set. Character class is `. /w /W /d /D /s /S ...`

Comment: So when you need solve some issues, sovle what you need

Comment: Thanks! How could I add a searchText variable (function argument) to a regular expression?

Comment: @user889349 See at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029109/javascript-regex-how-to-put-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

```js
const re = /(?<=\[\[)[^\]]+(?=]])/gm
const string = `-- You are likely to find [[children]] in [[a school]]
-- [[school]] is for [[learning]]`

console.log(string.match(re))

const replacement = {
  children: 'adults',
  'a school': 'a home',
  school: 'home',
  learning: 'rest',
}

console.log(string.split(/(?<=\[\[)[^\]]+(?=]])/).map((part, index) => part + (replacement[string.match(re)[index]] || '')).join(''))
```

Comment: https://github.com/Piterden/js-create-includes-webpack-plugin/blob/master/js-create-includes-webpack-plugin.js