# Using variables in URL validation

Tags: typescript, automation, playwright

I'm trying to use a variable in the URL assertion but not having any luck.

```
    const LAST = page.locator('#Selector1');
    const LastResult = page.locator('#Selector2').textContent();

    await page.goto(Env.baseUrl + '/Search');

    await (LAST).click();
    await expect(page).toHaveURL(/Search#page=('LastResult')/);
```

I'm expecting whatever TEXT to be in LastResult to be read in .toHaveURL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Regex: How to put a variable inside a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029109/javascript-regex-how-to-put-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression) or better: [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: I ended up figuring it out...
`
    const LAST = page.locator('#Selector1');
    const LastResult = page.locator('#Selector2').textContent();

    await page.goto(Env.baseUrl + '/Search');

    await (LAST).click();
    await LastResult.then(function(responce){
            expect(page).toHaveURL(`${Env.baseUrl}/Search#page=${responce}`);
    });
`

Comment: Great. Feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding a function in .then

```
const LAST = page.locator('#Selector1');
const LastResult = page.locator('#Selector2').textContent();

await page.goto(Env.baseUrl + '/Search');

await (LAST).click();
await LastResult.then(function(response) {
        expect(page).toHaveURL(`${Env.baseUrl}/Search#page=${response}`);
      });
```