# How can I increment a number matched via regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am adding a new field in one of my web apps, for visitors to add a product.  Pushing "add a product" clones one of the existing inputs, and I set it to a blank value.

I need to update the name however. The name is in this format:

```
<input type="text" name="product[0][0][3][title]" value="my product" id="input-AbGHtQS3" maxlength="150" />
```

I need to increment the last numerical index, that is the 3 in this example.

I wrote a regex to match the appropriate character, but how can I increment that last number?

Here is my regex:

```
/^product\[\d+\]\[\d+\]\[(\d+)\]\[.+\]/
```

How could I increment that last number?

Comment: why would you put what looks like a Javascript array in the name? Doing an eval on it later?

Comment: So I can work with it easily in PHP as an array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from: [Use RegExp to match a parenthetical number then increment it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423107/use-regexp-to-match-a-parenthetical-number-then-increment-it)

The replace method can take a function as its second argument. It gets the match (including submatches) and returns the replacement string. Others have already mentioned that the parentheses need to be escaped.

```
"Item Name (4)".replace(/\((\d+)\)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
    return "(" + (Number(n) + 1) + ")";
});
```

So,

*edit:

this should work

```
"product[0][0][3][title]".replace(/(^product\[\d+\]\[\d+\]\[)(\d+)(\]\[.+\])/, function(fullMatch, n, a, o) {
    return n + (Number(a) + 1) + o;
});
```

Comment: Didn't know you could give an anonymous function as 2nd argument! Learn something new every day. Thanks a bunch, will implement now.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work - see http://jsbin.com/obila/edit it is returning 4 - is that correct? How would I then make the name attribute read correctly? i.e. 'product[0][0][4][title]'

Comment: Ah crap, it's replacing the whole match. I'll give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

A more iterative approach:

```
r = /^(product\[\d+\]\[\d+\]\[)(\d+)(\]\[[a-z]+\])$/;
m = s.match(r);
if (!m) { /* do something smart; */ }
s.replace(r, "$1" + (Number(m[2]) + 1) + "$3");
```

I added a capture group at the head and tail of your regex. Then match, increment, and reassemble the string.

+1 for the match function on the regex though, I didn't know that trick.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912536/need-help-with-a-javascript-regex/1912578#1912578), but corrected to return entire string:

```
"product[0][0][3][title]".replace (
    /^(product\[\d+\]\[\d+\]\[)(\d+)(\]\[.+\])/,
    function(fullMatch, pre, n, post) {
        return pre + (Number(n) + 1) + post;
    }
);
```