# Replace part of value by incrementing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of inputs which can be duplicated, but I then need to increment the array value of them. How do I do this?

```
<input type="text" name="person[0][name]">
<input type="text" name="person[0][age]">
```

This can then be duplicated, but I need to change the new inputs to be like:

```
<input type="text" name="person[1][name]">
<input type="text" name="person[1][age]">
```

I have got so far:

```
cloned.find('input, select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.attr('name',
        $this.attr('name').match(/\[\d+]/g, '[' + what_goes_here + ']')
    );
});
```

Where `cloned` is my last group of inputs.

What do I do with the value of `what_goes_here`?

Comment: Use `replace` with captured group. `$this.attr('name', function(i, name) {
    return name.replace(/\[(\d+)]/g, function(m, $1) {
        return '[' + (Number($1) + 1) + ']';
    });
});`

Comment: Are the elements both cloned and possibly later removed from `document`?

Comment: No, can't be removed from document, Only the last element is cloned and then incremented.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912536/how-can-i-increment-a-number-matched-via-regex will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `\d+`, `+` operator, `.replace()`

```
cloned.find('input, select').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var n = $this.attr('name').match(/\d+/)[0];
    $this.attr('name', $this.attr('name').replace(n, +n + 1));
});
```