# How to increment a number within square brackets in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long string where I need to increment every number within it, leaving the rest of the text as it is.

I'm using this function

```
newHtml = newHtml.replace(/\d+/, function (val) { return parseInt(val) + 1; });
```

Which works great on numbers that are in free text but fails when the numbers are surrounded by square brackets. Example:

```
<input id="Form[0]_Phone" name="Form[0].Phone" type="text" value="">
```

Needs to become

```
<input id="Form[1]_Phone" name="Form[1].Phone" type="text" value="">
```

I've used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423107/use-regexp-to-match-a-parenthetical-number-then-increment-it) to try and help, and I've tried a few variations but my regex skills have failed me.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in your pattern causing the described behaviour - numbers in square brackets should also be affected. One obvious issue is you're affecting only the first number found, not all - add the `g` global flag after the closing forward slash of the pattern.

Works for me - see this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypUmg/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 'global' flag, then it should replace all occurences.

i.e.

`newHtml = newHtml.replace(/\d+/g, function (val) { return parseInt(val) + 1; });`

See it working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4S7CE/

Without 'g', it would replace only first instance of the match.