# jquery/javascript: what is the shortest way of expressing the accessing and altering of a substring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring, increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use RegExp to match a parenthetical number then increment it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423107/use-regexp-to-match-a-parenthetical-number-then-increment-it)

I know how to implement the solution already but with several ines of code; I'm wondering if there is a short and clever way of accessing the substring of a string that is an integer and incrementing it, where the substring isn't enclosed in any markup tags?

```
/*Let's say the string is*/ "<span class="ideacount">[5 ideas]</span>"
```

and I want to increment it to say "[6 ideas]".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var spanContent = $('#ideaCount').text();    
var i = parseInt(spanContent.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''));
i+=1;
$('#ideaCount').text( spanContent.replace(/[0-9\.]+/g, i+1) );
```

Just add some error checking.

Comment: Should have really thought a bit before posting as I came up with a single-line solution (minus variable declaration):

    $(this).html(" [" + ((v = $(this).text().match(/\d/) || 0),++v) +" idea" + (v>1?"s":"") + "]");

Unless anyone can make it even leaner?